# Postgres in a docker container not working - constantly restarting

Tags: postgresql, docker

I've recently moved copied my postgres data from one hard drive to another.

My docker run command is

```
    docker run --name postgres --restart=always -e 
 POSTGRES_USER= -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD= -e POSTGRES_DB=elevate_recruit -v /media/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d -p 543
2:5432 postgres:9.5
```

Where the media drive is a drive that contains the postgres backup. 
When I run `ls -l media/postgres` I get

```
drwxrw-rw-  6 sbt springcoil 4096 Jun 20 10:25 base
drwxrw-rw- 19 sbt springcoil 4096 Jun 21 13:27 data
-rw-rw-rw-  1 sbt springcoil    4 Apr 27 13:38 PG_VERSION
```

When I run the docker container and do `docker logs container_id` I get

`postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory`

Edit - the data/postgres.conf file exists.

Am I missing something should I be changing the docker permissions? Should I be changing something? I'm a bit stumped and frustrated by this error.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution to this problem.

Firstly make sure to do `sudo usermod -aG docker your_user` and then log back in. 
Also make sure you've got `chmod 777` and `chmod -R your_user:your_user` on your folders.

Finally there is actually an error in my docker run command. It should be `-v /media/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql` instead of `-v /media/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data` thanks to whoever on a Slack channel (Dave Challis I think) pointed this out.

Comment: just nothing that it's rarely ever a good idea to chmod 777. The problem is obviously a permissions problem. But making the files/folders available to all is a bad idea.